How do I set Xcode 16 so that when I create a new project it defaults to support minimum iOS to iOS 12.0
I want to be able to support iOS 12.0 in my iOS apps that I create using Xcode. (Xcode 16.0) How do I set Xcode so that when I create a new project, the minimum iOS version supported is iOS 12, so it's not using Scenes.

How far have you gotten? Have you set the iOS to 12.0, and you just want this to happen every time? Or have you set the version to that, but have run into issues with the templates using Scenes rather than the legacy approach?

I haven't gotten anywhere with it except looking for a way to do that in Xcode's Settings or Preferences. I've been manually replacing the new project's Info.plist with a separate saved Info.plist file, changing the code in AppDelegate.swift, deleting the SceneDelegate.swift, and setting the iOS version to 12.0 in the project settings and making sure it reflects in the target.

You should probably just create a "base-template" project.
I don't think that Xcode has the legacy templates from the previous eras.
